# "bash shell" reading in sections from a file

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting. Getting really hooked on text mate also. Anyways I have a txt file that contains something like as follows.....

```
Smith:David:111 Oak St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80901
Smith:Tina:111 Oak St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80901
Martin:Steve:2233 Cascade St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80907
```

I'm trying to create a program that will read it in and display in the following format.

```
Jane Doe
5245 Anystreet St.
Any City, State 22222

John Doe
2245 Anystreet St.
Any City, State 22222
```

I can't find beginner friendly documentation on what commands to use and how to use them. A few sights give great in depth documentation but it's hard to follow. I would like to implement the sort command and sort it by zipcode but I can't get a good example to follow. Can someone help me figure this out or help me get started?

----------------------------------------Further Questions "Updated"------------------------------

Thanks for the advice and it has helped out greatly. I wrote the program a few different ways however I have a few last questions on one example another student did. Don't quite understand everything in their code. I've put my questions as comments.

[image]

Comment: How are we meant to map Colorado Springs to Any City? :D It's best to be consistent with input and output data.

Answer (score 5):

The task is trivial if you can use `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{print $2,$1 ORS $3 ORS $4", "$5,$6 ORS}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
Smith:David:111 Oak St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80901
Smith:Tina:111 Oak St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80901
Martin:Steve:2233 Cascade St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80907
```

```
$ awk -F: '{print $2,$1 ORS $3 ORS $4", "$5,$6 ORS}' file
David Smith
111 Oak St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80901

Tina Smith
111 Oak St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80901

Steve Martin
2233 Cascade St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80907
```

You can use arrays in bash and do:

```
while IFS=: read -ra line; do 
  printf "%s %s\n%s\n%s, %s %s %s\n\n" "${line[1]}" "${line[0]}" "${line[2]}" "${line[3]}" "${line[4]}" "
${line[5]}"; 
done < file
```

**Output**

```
David Smith
111 Oak St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80901 

Tina Smith
111 Oak St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80901 

Steve Martin
2233 Cascade St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80907
```

Comment: What exactly are those $2 $1 etc... commands saying. Having a hard time understanding the syntax.

Comment: @ShaneYost What `awk` does is breaks the input line into variables which can be referenced by using `$` sigil along with the number. We did `-F:` which tells `awk` to break the line on `:`. `$2` is referencing the second word. `$1` the first word and so on ... `ORS` is awk builtin variable whose default value is `"\n"`. So I used that instead of using `"\n"`.

Comment: Could you help explain some questions I added in the picture I attached above. It's an example of another persons way of doing it. I just had a hard time understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set IFS to colon and then exploit that, carefully:

```
$ cat > xyz
Smith:David:111 Oak St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80901
Smith:Tina:111 Oak St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80901
Martin:Steve:2233 Cascade St.:Colorado Springs:CO:80907
$ while read line
> do (IFS=:
>     set -- $line
>     echo $2 $1
>     echo $3
>     echo $4, $5 $6
>     echo
>    )
> done < xyz
David Smith
111 Oak St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80901

Tina Smith
111 Oak St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80901

Steve Martin
2233 Cascade St.
Colorado Springs, CO 80907

$
```

The use of a sub-shell is optional, but means that `IFS` in the main shell is not changed — usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thy this simple one:

```
cat file | sed -r 's/(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)/\1 \2\n\3\n\4,\5 \6\n/'
```

Comment: You can avoid using `cat` since `sed` can take input from file directly using `sed ... file`

Comment: True. But I always use, and always recommend using, cat to pipe into commands if possible. This way the file name is always very clear so you can change it easily (as opposed to it being somewhere in a list of arguments). Also, if you need to make any small change to the input before you run, e.g., `sed`, you can do it more easily.